# OSX Reformat and Restore with Time Machine

Tags: windows-7, macos, hard-drive, partitioning, boot-camp

After learning that Windows 32Bit limits Ram under 4GB, I decided to reformat the partition and install Windows 64Bit through Bootcamp. My goal now is to create a partition of 150GB.

***Here is what I have:***

- MacbookPro 2010 (OSX 10.6.8)
- 1TB external Hard drive that can be used to create a backup with Time Machine
- The OSX 10.6.3 install DVD
- The Windows 7 64Bit install DVD
- 250GB free space on the internal disk
- Coffee and determination

I already removed the partition through bootcamp and tried to create a new one. But I got the error message that the partition could not be created because some files could not be moved. Apparently this is a common issue and I followed some tricks to solve the problem without prevail.

***Here is what I have done so far:***

- I verified disk and repaired disk permission from the disk utilities on the internal disk both in normal and safe mode. I tried to re-create a partition and got the same error in bootcamp as mentioned above.
- I used the Erase Free Space function from the disk utilities on the internal disk. I tried to re-create a partition and again the same error.

So I was thinking, the only way to clean up this Internal hard disk is to completely reformat the internal disk and restore my backup, then create a bootcamp partition.

***My are my questions:***

1. If I make a backup on Time Machine and restore onto formated drive **will it also restore the library and system files such as Ruby and Rails installs, Ruby gems, RVM, Git and Terminal bash files?** I do not want to re-install all these resources.
2. I am looking for a comprehensive and best practice guide to create a backup on Time Machine, Then reformat my internal disk and restore from Time Machine all my files.

Thank you so much in advance for your answers!